# About the absolute value and the place on a number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Let $K$ be a number field.  The place $\nu$ is an equivalence class of non-trivial absolute values. Moreover, the absolute value $| \quad | : K \to \mathbb{R}$ is called non-archimedean if $$|x+ y| \leq \max(|x|, |y|), \forall \ x, y \in K.$$  Then, one has

"there is only one archimedean place $\infty$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ given by the ordinary absolute value $| \quad |$."

I am reading this proposition, but I can't prove its. Can you help me to send a proof for that? Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't understand the question. 1) $\infty$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q$. 2) If absolute values (i.e., functions from $K$ to $\mathbb R$) are archimedean, then how can an equivalence class be archimedean? That's like saying a number is increasing (when "increasing" is not a property of a number, it's a property of a function).

Comment: @5xum The (equivalence class of the) absolute value is often called the “infinite place” on $ℚ$. Furthermore, it can be proven that an absolute value is archimedean if all other equivalent absolute values are archimedean, so it makes sense to talk about places being archimedean.

Comment: More generally, you can prove that the $p$-adic absolute value for all the primes $p$ and the ordinary absolute value are all the absolute values up to equivalence on $\mathbb Q$. This is called Ostrowski's theorem and find a proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski's_theorem#Proof

Comment: Thank you so much @Ravi for your link!

Comment: @5xum In case the downvote and close-vote are yours – I think you should remove them. The question seems quite clear to me. Your objections are invalid, as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$
Obviously, the absolute value is an archimedean place.

Furthermore, you should try to prove that any absolute value $\abs{~}\colon K → [0..∞)$ on any field $K$ is non-archimedean if and only if it is bounded on $ℕ$ (and then it’s bounded from below by $1$).

One direction is pretty clear by induction, for the other you should use the binomial theorem: Prove for $x, y ∈ K$ with $x ≠ 0$, $y ≠ 0$ and $\abs{x} ≤ \abs{y}$,
$$\abs{x+y} = \sqrt[n]{\abs{x+y}^n} \quad\text{and}\quad\abs{x+y}^n ≤ (n+1)\abs{y}^n.$$
You will need $\abs{~}$ being bounded on $ℕ$ for the last inequality. Then take the limit $n → ∞$.

Now, being multiplicative, an archimedean absolute value on $ℚ$ restricts to a multiplicative monoid homomorphism $ℕ → [0..∞)$. Since it’s unbounded (as we now know), there must be a prime $p ∈ ℕ$ with $\abs{p} > 1$. Without loss of generality (by replacing $\abs{~}$ by $\abs{~}^{\log_{\abs p}~p}$) we may assume $\abs{p} = p$, so $\abs{p^k} = p^k$ for all $k ∈ ℕ$.

Also $\abs{1} = 1$. By induction, $\abs{n} ≤ n$. Now if there was any $m ∈ ℕ$ with $\abs{m} < m$, then, by induction $\abs{n} < n$, for all $n ≥ m$. But $\abs{p^k} = p^k$ for *all* $k ∈ ℕ$, so we have $\abs{n} = n$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$.

Since $\pm ℕ$ generates $ℚ^×$ as group multiplicatively, this determines the group homomorphism $\abs{~} \colon ℚ^× → (0..∞)$ completely. And $\abs{0} = 0$.